# can I reupload my magento package extension in magento connect after 2 days of submitted?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, package

I submitted(2 days ago) my package extension in magento connect website for review.Now I realized that I added wrong PHP version while creating package extension.I created package extension using magento version 1.9.Can I now add new extension version and upload  or wait reply from magento connect team ? what I do in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add as many packages as you want even if you did not have the reply from magento connect team I've done it several times without issues